# Changing the xml structure when I use WriteXML converting DataSet to xml?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset, writexml

The following puts content of an excel file (one worksheet; one column) into a DataSet that needs to be an excel string:

[image]

```
        DataSet ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ds.WriteXml(sw);
        string result = sw.ToString();
```

it returns the following string:

```
<NewDataSet>
<Sheet2><Column1>70209429072734</Column1></Sheet2>
<Sheet2><Column1>30221442748624</Column1></Sheet2>
<Sheet2><Column1>70209433124464</Column1></Sheet2>
<Sheet2><Column1>30209434466634</Column1></Sheet2>
</NewDataSet>
```

**I want it in this format:**

```
<DLN>
   <id>70209429072734</id>
   <id>30221442748624</id>
   <id>70209433124464</id>
   <id>30209434466634</id>
</DLN>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Find And Replace XML Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794027/c-sharp-find-and-replace-xml-nodes) ?

Comment: Anyway to avoid needing to iterate thru records to create my format?

Comment: I doubt it. If it's possible I'd love to know how as well.