# How to replace tag name with empty string in xml DOM?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldom

based on xml below:

```
<TEST>
<TEST2>
Sample text
</TEST2>
</TEST>
```

how can i replace `<TEST2>` with `Empty.string` or "". This is the expected output:

```
<TEST>

Sample text

</TEST>
```

Comment: Do you want to flatten just the `<TEST2>` or do you want to flatten a whole document (i.e you have `<TEST3>` inside `<TEST2>` and `<TEST4>` being a sibling of `<TEST2>`, you'd end up with just `<TEST>`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6794027/c-sharp-find-and-replace-xml-nodes

Comment: @MindSwipe just <TEST2>

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const { DOMParser } = require('xmldom')

const rawXmlData = `
<?xml version = "1.0">
<TEST>
<TEST2>
Sample text
</TEST2>
<TEST2>
Another Sample text
</TEST2>
</TEST>
`;

const domParser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString(rawXmlData,"text/xml");
const tagsToRemove = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('TEST2'); // 2 elements
xmlDoc.removeChild(tagsToRemove);
const tagsThatGotRemoved = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('TEST2');
console.log(tagsThatGotRemoved.length); // 0
```